# How to pass files from a certain path to certain function using for loop (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to convert a bunch of pdf to images using python

Here is my code :

Could someone help me by clarifying what I am  doing wrong here

```
import os
import cv2
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os
import sys
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import threading


arr = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf')

print(arr)

outputDir = (r"C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes")


def convert(file, outputDir):
    outputDir = outputDir + str(round(time.time())) + '/'
    if not os.path.exists(outputDir):
        os.makedirs(outputDir)

    pages = convert_from_path(file, 500)
    counter = 1
    for page in pages:
        myfile = outputDir +'output' + str(counter) +'.jpg'
        counter = counter + 1
        page.save(myfile, "JPEG")
        return (myfile)


for file in arr:
    myfile = convert('C:\\User\\Ramesh\\Desktop\\Parsing_Project\\Resumes_pdf\\' + file, outputDir)
```

The error that I am getting is like the below screenshot

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a way to pass address of files from certain path and loop over each files using the blob function**

*Here is the code I used :*

```
address_list = []
outputDir = (r"C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes")


def convert(file, outputDir):
    outputDir = outputDir + str(round(time.time())) + '/'
    if not os.path.exists(outputDir):
        os.makedirs(outputDir)

    pages = convert_from_path(file, 500)
    counter = 1
    for page in pages:
        myfile = outputDir +'output' + str(counter) +'.jpg'
        counter = counter + 1
        page.save(myfile, "JPEG")
        return (myfile)



for file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf/**/*.pdf', recursive=True):

    address_list.append(file)
    
print(address_list)

for file in address_list:
    
    myfile = convert(file, outputDir)
```

**Thanks for your help :)**

Answer (score 2):

The `arr` contains the names for the files in the directory `C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf`.

You are trying to open a file but at a wrong location.
Try changing the code to:

```
for file in arr:
    myfile = convert('C:\\User\\Ramesh\\Desktop\\Parsing_Project\\Resumes_pdf\\' + file, outputDir)
```

Note that backslashes must be escaped with backslashes, else the closing quote will not be recognized by python and give an EOL (End Of Line) error.

Comment: its showing 'eol while scanning string' , Then I tried ```myfile = convert(r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf'  + file, outputDir)``` But the problem with the output is ``` Couldn't open file 'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdfAkhil.pdf': No error.``` How to bring a " \ " between Parsing_Project and Akhil.pdf ?

Comment: @RahulRamesh I edited the answer, it will work now

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia backslashes have to be escaped with backslashes to become real backslashes, else they escape the following character.

Comment: @frederic The error is gone now, But due to the double backslashes I think, the file is not opening

Comment: @RahulRamesh __Does__ it not open or do you only think so ?

Comment: @RahulRamesh Is it giving an error, then post it please in your question.

Comment: @frederic I just posted the latest  screenshot at the end . The EOL error was gone with the double backslashes , But the system is not able to read the file with double backslashes

Comment: @RahulRamesh your file path strings have an r in front. Remove that, and it should work.

Comment: @RahulRamesh and please post the errors in as text in the future !

Comment: i removed the r and its still showing error as ``` File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 471, in pdfinfo_from_path
    raise PDFPageCountError(
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'C:\User\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf\Akhil.pdf': No error.
```

Comment: @RahulRamesh maybe is your PDF corrupted ? Try to open it in a pdf viewer.

Comment: @RahulRamesh errors as text yes, but not in the comments, please ! If you changed your code and are getting another error, update the code and the error in your question !

Comment: got it @frederic

Comment: @frederic not yet brother . Still looking into it

Comment: @RahulRamesh were you able to open the pdf in a pdf viewer ?

Comment: @frederic yes . I doubt whether the problem have anything to do with my pdf2image

Comment: @RahulRamesh then, update it with `python.exe -m pip install -U pdf2image` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this code, it just opens the pdf files and reads one line, without involving `pdf2image`:

```py
import os

arr = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Ramesh\\Desktop\\Parsing_Project\\Resumes_pdf')

print(arr)

def convert(file):
    f = open(file, "r")
    print(f.readline())

for file in arr:
    convert('C:\\User\\Ramesh\\Desktop\\Parsing_Project\\Resumes_pdf\\' + file)
```

If it prints out the lines without errors, the pdf files are ok and the paths too, so your `pdf2image` must be broken, else please post the errors so that i can help you further.

Comment: I solved the issue by using glob function . Do you want to the see the code ?

Comment: @RahulRamesh make an answer with it and accept that answer